# CSS Media Query | Image Responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been researching how to use media queries properly, below is the site I'm trying to make responsive. However, I'm finding trouble adjusting the image of my picture, I test the responsiveness on my PC, which is 17 inches and also on my Galaxy 5.

**edit, the problem is solved for me

```
.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background:url(nycgold.jpg) fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding-top: 13%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* styles for narrow screens */
    .background-image{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
    /* styles for MacBook Pro-sized screens and larger */
    .background-image{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're not changing anything, the width is still 100%, what is it exactly you want to do?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do can be done with background-size:cover and there is no need for media queries.  Check out the following fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/rqgLax2p/

Comment: @SamirChahine For the smaller MQ, I just put that code as a placeholder since I've tried other things, but it didn't work. To answer your question, I'm trying to make the image on the site uniform, no repetition, and fitted to the size of the screen for smaller displays. However, if you were to reduce the width of the site, there would a display of my image repeated twice, and I don't want that. I don't know what to put inside the class when the screen size is small.

Comment: @y17 See my answer, hope it's what you wanted, good luck.

Comment: @SamirChahine Thank you, I think I fixed it :D

Comment: @DrinkinPeople Thank you, I think that fixed it.

Comment: @y17 It's worth posting how you fixed it for anyone with the same problem in future. (Or marking an answer as accepted if someone helped you out :) )

Comment: Glad to have helped! @DBS I was just about to say, just didn't know how :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've got 3 styles here:

1. The default style
2. The style for max-width:320px
3. The style for max-width:1800px

But all three styles set the background image to the same size. Backgrounds are not really something that you need to write responsive code for because they generally try to fit the browser's rendering area, but `background-size:cover` set once in the main style would ask the browser to fill the background with the entire image, so setting widths isn't necessary.

**See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size for more information about the background-size CSS property.**

To test out your media queries, make sure that there are DIFFERENT values set for elements in them and use something that is better suited to responsive, like an image in the foreground. `<img src="">` or text size of an element.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is for the background to show once, with no repetition, add this `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Other than that, your image should fit the whole width of whatever size the MQ is.